# Powershell - Match and replace

Tags: powershell

Trying to match and replace, while keeping order of content in file.

```
(Get-Content output.txt) |
    ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match ".mp4") {$_ -replace "img", "source"} } | Set-content output.txt
```

output.txt:

```
<img src="img_a.PNG">
<img src="video_1.mp4">
<img src="img_b.PNG">
<img src="video_2.mp4">
```

The output is:

```
<source src="video_1.mp4">
<source src="video_2.mp4">
```

But I'm trying to have it:

```
<img src="img_a.PNG">
<source src="video_1.mp4">
<img src="img_b.PNG">
<source src="video_2.mp4">
```

Seems to be overwriting it?

Comment: If you append an `else {$_} ` to the `if (...){...}`the lines not matching will be output unchanged. Otherwise @mklement0 solution is more elegant(+1).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
(Get-Content output.txt) -replace '<img (?=.+\.mp4)', '<source ' |
  Set-Content output.txt
```

<sup>This could be made more robust, but works with the sample input.</sup>

The above relies on:

- a (positive) lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`) that matches part of the input without considering it part of the overall match and therefore not replacing it.
- `-replace` passing any non-matching inputs through as-is.

---

As for **what you tried**:

By only producing output if condition `if ($_ -match ".mp4")` is true, you're effectively *omitting* the input lines that do not match `.mp4`.

Comment: I forgot to thank you! This worked, thank you. Also thank you for explaining the difference of what was going on, much appreciated!